# 'None' returned from a call to '.get()' issue

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping, nonetype

Getting a None returned from a call to `.get()` could mean that the key wasn't found or that the value found at the key in the dictionary is actually None.

So what can I set the return value to if nothing is found and interpreted has 0 in boolean test?

for write this:

```
ages = {'Jim': 30, 'Pam': 28, 'Kevin': None}
person = input('Get age for: ')
age = ages.get(person, ?) #what need to be '?'

if age:
    print(f'{person} is {age} years old.')
else:
    print(f"{person}'s age is unknown.")
```

Comment: So you want to return something if the ```key:value``` was not found?

Comment: @Sujay i want return something else than None with the .get(key, here), because .get(key) return by default None if no key find, but None can be in data associed to a key as in my exemple. .get(key, 0) is a bad idea too because 0 can be a valide data associed to a key meaning the person has < 0 years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `.get`. Just access the dictionary value directly.

Like this:

```
ages = {'Jim': 30, 'Pam': 28, 'Kevin': None}
person = input('Get age for: ')

try:
    age = ages[person]
    
    if age:
        print(f'{person} is {age} years old.')
    else:
        print(f"{person}'s age is unknown.")
except KeyError:
    print(f"Unknown person: {person}")
```

Comment: And if a ```KeyError``` is raised, you could catch the exception too.

Comment: @Sujay yeah I am working on an edit right now

Comment: @MarkoBorković so in wich case .get() method is needed ? (you can answer me : "google it" , i will accept it)

Comment: .get() allows to the script to continue running and does not raise a KeyError (which stops the script running).  
It's basically the same as writing ```dictionary["Age"] or None``` so it implicitly handles KeyError exception.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it would be useful to use try/except:

```
ages = {'Jim': 30, 'Pam': 28, 'Kevin': None}
person = input('Get age for: ')
try:
    age = ages[person] #what need to be '?'
    if age:
        print(f'{person} is {age} years old.')
    else:
        print(f"{person}'s age is unknown.")
except KeyError:
    print(f'{person} not found in ages')
```

output

```
Get age for: Jim
Jim is 30 years old.

Get age for: Kevin
Kevin's age is unknown.

Get age for: Bob
Bob not found in ages
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
ages = {'Jim': 30, 'Pam': 28, 'Kevin': None}
person = input('Get age for: ')

try:
    age = ages[person]
    
    if age:
        print(f'{person} is {age} years old.')
    else:
        print(f"{person}'s age is unknown.")
except KeyError:
    print(f"{person} is not known.")
```

Comment: But How you differencied kevin which has None as age and seb who is not is the dictonarry ?

Comment: @seb16120 The else statement will be returned if the key is valid but the value is None.  The ```except KeyError``` will be returned if the key e.g. Seb does not exist.